# Filezilla on Mac: SFTP with passwordless authentication?

Tags: filezilla, ssh-agent

I am trying to follow the instructions here for OSX

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto

I can successfully `ssh` to the target server with no username/password (OSX picks up my certificates from the `~/.ssh` directory), but I have no idea how to get Filezilla to do the same.

I have tried just running `ssh-agent` which doesn't do much.

Comment: By "FTP over SSH", did you mean SFTP, or _real_ old FTP tunnelled over SSH?

Comment: Did you follow the *Windows* part of the tutorial, or the single sentence relating to *other platforms*?

Comment: @Daniel Beck, "other platforms"... @grawity, I mean SFTP, not FTP tunnelled over SSH.

Comment: Do you get any output in the Terminal when you type `printenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK`?

Comment: @William Jackson: `/tmp/launch-xi2Fu5/Listeners`

Comment: Can you post the error text in the log at the top of the window when you try to connect?

Comment: @william Jackson: `Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: Which is the idea, since I've shut off "regular" authentication.

Comment: but I have the RSA private key which the server knows about, hence I can ssh in.

Comment: AFAIK. RSA was made to authenticate with your OWN key´s password, not passwordless

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can now use `FileZilla -> Preferences -> Connection -> SFTP` which will allow you to import your private key.

Comment: `Command-Shift-G` and enter: `~/.ssh` to go to your `.ssh` directory

Comment: (translating from my language) "~/.ssh/id_rsa is not in a supported format. Additionally it's password protected. Filezilla doesn't support password protected keys yet. Do you want to convert the file to the supported unprotected format?" No, thanks...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without importing your key? It worked fine for me without this until very recently in 2018.

Comment: @SammyLarbi sorry, I don't remember this topic very well. However, the instructions were tried at the time and worked.

Answer (score 7):

Recent versions of OSX have the ssh-agent built-in and there is no need to start it separately.

In my case I simply had to change the logon type to "interactive" in the sites settings in FileZilla and choose SFTP as the protocol.

FileZilla apparently talks with the ssh-agent and handles the authentication. This is better than importing the key to FileZilla, since this way you can keep the file password protected.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `.ppk` or `.pem` keys.

1. Add your private key to the SSH agent. In Mac, this is `ssh-add ~/.ssh/[your private key]` - if you haven't created SSH keys then run this command first `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[give a name for your keys] -C "[your email]"`
2. 1) Open FileZilla 2) Type host: `sftp://[host ip address you want to connect to]` 3) Type username: `[your username]` 4) Leave password and port fields empty 5) Click Quickconnect

FileZilla will be able to use the keys you've loaded in the SSH agent automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Both instructions on this page tell 3/4 of the story:

Yar is correct: you only have to go to the SFTP settings page to enter your SSH key (which I had to format as a putty key with a .ppk extension - FileZilla will format a normal ssh private key for you if you let it).

ddd is correct that you have to put your login into "Normal" mode (but you still also need the key entered on the SFTP settings).

But there is one more thing you have to have in your settings - you must allow FileZilla to save passwords. This is in the Preferences -> Interface: If you check the box that says "Do Not Save Passwords" you will not be permitted to use Normal mode, and then your ssh won't be utilized - you will be prompted for a password.

**So, do all three steps:**

1. Import SSH Key on the SFTP settings page.
2. Do not check the box that says "Do Not Save Passwords" (i.e., allow saving passwords)
3. Use Normal mode in the General tab of the server profile settings.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me on MacOS (Sierra, High Sierra, or Mojave).  Adding your own key to FileZilla Settings still prompts for a password after reboot.

Add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
UseKeychain yes  
AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then do this in the terminal:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then create this file:

~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.computername.AddSSHKeysAtLogin.plist

Put this in it:

Label
local.mycomputername.AddSSHKeysAtLogin
ProgramArguments

/usr/bin/ssh-add
-A

StandardOutPath
/dev/null
StandardErrorPath
/dev/null
RunAtLoad

Reboot and you should be able to use FileZilla without being prompted for a password.  It Works!

I got the last part here: https://blog.elao.com/en/tech/ssh-agent-does-not-automatically-load-passphrases-on-the-osx-sierra-keychain/

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Filezilla:

Top Menu: Filezilla -> Settings -> Connection/FTP/SFTP

Click `Add keyfile` to import the ppk file (there are a lot of pem to ppk converter if you only have pem private key)

Answer (score -2):

You have to put your server first in the server manager. Provide the IP/domain and username, and ensure the login type is set to "normal" then press login.

If you have a working SSH connection to this IP everything will be fine!